# How to solve the equation $\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{x!}\times \sqrt{x!!}\times \sqrt{x!!!}}{\sqrt{\left( x-2 \right)!+x}}}=12$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics, computational-science

Consider the following equation,

$$\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{x!}\times \sqrt{x!!}\times \sqrt{x!!!}}{\sqrt{\left( x-2 \right)!+x}}}=12$$
 I tried first to eliminates all radicals using squring both sides to get the following ,
$$\frac{\sqrt{x!}\times \sqrt{x!!}\times \sqrt{x!!!}}{\sqrt{\left( x-2 \right)!+x}}={{12}^{2}}\Leftrightarrow \frac{\sqrt{x!\times x!!\times x!!!}}{\sqrt{\left( x-2 \right)!+x}}=\frac{x!\times x!!\times x!!!}{\left( x-2 \right)!+x}={{12}^{4}}$$

Now how will continue attacking this problem?

Comment: Over which domain are you solving the equation?

Comment: over N positive integers

Comment: I suppose that $x$ must be $\geq 2$ since $(-1)!=\Gamma(0)$ is undefined. Also: Does $x!!!$ denote a [multifactorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multifactorial.html)?

Comment: Okay so since your function is increasing in $x$, you can just try out all integers until your function is greater than $12^4$

Comment: Already for $x=3$, we have $x!!!=720!$, which has many sizeable prime factors that will not be cancelled by the denominator, and it's much too big anyway.

Comment: @JohnBentin $x!!!$ is a [multifactorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multifactorial.html)  It doesn't mean $((x!)!)!$.

Comment: You can try $x = 10$ which gives a value of nearly $10^8$, much larger than $12^4$. There are only a few positive integers to try that are less than $10$, from which you can quickly get $x = 6$.

Comment: I did it this way.  $x=4$ is too small.  $x=5$ gives a factor of $5$ in the numerator, but not the denominator.  $x=6$ works.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have next to no intuition for the size of a potential solution, and don't want to try out small numbers by hand. Then we can use the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) in [an extension of the multifactorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial#Alternative_extension_of_the_multifactorial) to make this a continuous function so that a computer can more-easily help us hunt for the root.

By the calculations in the OP, with the equation with $12^4$, we can see at the very least that the solution probably isn't bigger than $12^2$, and likely much less. Let's just start looking around $150$: [Wolfram|Alpha says](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=FindRoot%5BSqrt%5BSqrt%5BGamma%5Bx%2B1%5D%5D*Sqrt%5B2%5E%28%28x-1%29%2F2%29*%28Gamma%5B1%2Bx%2F2%5D%29%2F%28Gamma%5B1%2B1%2F2%5D%29%5D*Sqrt%5B3%5E%28%28x-1%29%2F3%29*%28Gamma%5B1%2Bx%2F3%5D%29%2F%28Gamma%5B1%2B1%2F3%5D%29%5D%2FSqrt%5Bx%2BGamma%5Bx-2%2B1%5D%5D%5D%20-%2012%2C%20%7Bx%2C%20150%7D%5D) that $45.1$ would be a better guess. If you start at $45$, [it says](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=FindRoot%5BSqrt%5BSqrt%5BGamma%5Bx%2B1%5D%5D*Sqrt%5B2%5E%28%28x-1%29%2F2%29*%28Gamma%5B1%2Bx%2F2%5D%29%2F%28Gamma%5B1%2B1%2F2%5D%29%5D*Sqrt%5B3%5E%28%28x-1%29%2F3%29*%28Gamma%5B1%2Bx%2F3%5D%29%2F%28Gamma%5B1%2B1%2F3%5D%29%5D%2FSqrt%5Bx%2BGamma%5Bx-2%2B1%5D%5D%5D%20-%2012%2C%20%7Bx%2C%2045%7D%5D) that something around $6.2$ would be better. If you start at $6$, it's still thinking around $6.2$ (but these continuous functions are hard to approximate), so we should probably check around $6$ or $7$.

If we happen to choose $7$ first, [it says](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=N%5BSqrt%5BSqrt%5B7%21%5D*Sqrt%5B7*5*3%5D*Sqrt%5B7*4%5D%2FSqrt%5B%287%20-%202%29%21%20%2B%207%5D%5D%5D) the value is about $18.5$. And if we ask for [the value at 6](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sqrt%5BSqrt%5B6%21%5D*Sqrt%5B6*4*2%5D*Sqrt%5B6*3%5D%2FSqrt%5B%286%20-%202%29%21%20%2B%206%5D%5D), we find that it is indeed $12$.

Comment: If you add the option `MaxIterations -> 1000`, then it will instantly give out $6.211$. Interestingly, the Gamma function "rewriting" of the original function is not $=0$ at $6$, but indeed $=0$ at a number strictly larger than $6$ (see [plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5BSqrt%5BSqrt%5BGamma%5Bx%2B1%5D%5D*Sqrt%5B2%5E%28%28x-1%29%2F2%29*%28Gamma%5B1%2Bx%2F2%5D%29%2F%28Gamma%5B1%2B1%2F2%5D%29%5D*Sqrt%5B3%5E%28%28x-1%29%2F3%29*%28Gamma%5B1%2Bx%2F3%5D%29%2F%28Gamma%5B1%2B1%2F3%5D%29%5D%2FSqrt%5Bx%2BGamma%5Bx-2%2B1%5D%5D%5D+-+12%2C+%7Bx%2C+1%2C7%7D%5D))